# ng-option is replacing my default option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I am having a select tag as

```
 <select ng-model="vm.fooModel"
         ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.fooOptions" >
     <option value="none">Select</option>
 </select>
```

The issue is that when this is getting rendered angular 1.6 is removing my default option and adding an empty option

```
     <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

My initial model value for "vm.fooModel" is "none" . ̶T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶1̶.̶5̶

Comment: Why not just add an "empty" option to your `vm.fooOptions` collection?  And remove the hard-coded empty option?

Comment: From the documentation:  "Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, **with the value set to an empty string**, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option. See example below for demonstration."

Comment: @cale_b thanks for the response but i am sorry i cannot do that because that would be a hack on my system

Comment: @Amy , does this mean that we can now only add empty string as a default option from 1.6 ??

Comment: Yes.  Any other default value you must do as @cale_b suggested, and prepend the default value to the `ng-options` collection.  Or use ng-repeat, but that isn't recommended.

Comment: @Amy but this working in 1.5 they had changed something in 1.6 , can we figure out some angularjs directive hack or something ??

Comment: It's a breaking change.  You can write your own version of `ng-options`, but that is far more of a "hack on your system" than doing it the far simpler way.  I don't understand why the solutions presented aren't sufficient for you.  They're perfectly viable.

Comment: thanks for the responses @Amy can you please provide me with a  document where its mentioned as breaking change that would be very helpful

Comment: No.  Why?  You already know its a breaking change.  You said so yourself.  It was working in 1.5, it's not working in 1.6.  That is the very definition of "breaking change".  Besides, you have Google available.

Comment: thanks i got that https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md , 1.6.0 , just want to confirm its a breaking change or not

Comment: `ng-options` removes  options in version 1.5. See [THIS PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/tGbxUSh1xzltghhzFpNT?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-repeat` method for `<select>` options:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.fooModel="none";
  vm.fooOptions=[
    {id: 1, name:"one"},
    {id: 2, name:"two"},
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.fooModel">
      <option value="none" disabled>Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in vm.fooOptions" ng-value="item.id">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>   
    </select>
    value={{vm.fooModel}}
 </body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options).

Comment: added default attribute so user can't re-select the default option.

Answer (score 0):

Add default option to array of options in controller.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.fooModel = "none";
    vm.fooOptions = [{
        id: "none",
        name: "default"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "one"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "two"
      },
    ];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <select ng-model="vm.fooModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.fooOptions">
  </select>

  Select: {{vm.fooModel}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option ng-repeat="item in vm.fooOptions track by item.id" ng-value="item.id">
```

make use of track by in ng-repeat